# How to check how much data has changed without storing two versions

Tags: algorithm, diff, checksum

I'd like to check how much of the data in a (text) file has changed between two runs of a batch job that generates a file. Since the file becomes very large, I'd like to avoid storing the old file and creating a diff with the new file. I don't care much about the exact number of bytes changed, a percentage would suffice. The file sizes may vary between runs. Is there an algorithm that does that?

Comment: What is the nature of differences? Is it only addition, only removing or it can be mixed? Do differences usually touch single bytes or big chunks?

Comment: The data is CSV data. Lines can be removed and added. A field in a line can be changed. So changes may run from 1 byte to 2000 Bytes plus or minus. Lines in different order should not contribute to the change count if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a generic algorithm that does this. But given your constraints then I think its pretty straightforward.

Calculate a 32-bit hash of every line in the CSV and store them in a sorted array. You then compare hashes. If 10% of your hashes have changed then likely 10% of your file has changed. ( as a percentage of lines )

If this is too large, then calculate the 32-bit hash of each csv line, but store the last 8 bits of each hash in a histogram. E.g. if you have 10 hashes where the last byte was 0, then hist[0] = 10. You can then compute roughly how many lines have changed.

This structure would be really small - like 256 32-bit numbers. ( about 1k )

This is not perfect since when a line changes it moves to another bucket, but some lines in that bucket may also come out, masking the ones that went in. This is a problem with hash collisions. As you store more bits the data structure gets larger, but more accurate since the hash collisions will be fewer.

You can increase or decrease your odds of a hash collision by increasing the number of hash bits you use in your histogram. For example if you did this using the lower 12 bits of each hash, your hash collisions would be many fewer - the data structure could be 4k 32-bit numbers, or 16k.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't look like a finished idea, may be it will point to better ones.

Divide the initial file into blocks. Compute hash of every block. Store these hashes.

For the new file use the same block size, but split it into blocks in a different (adaptive) way. Start from block starting at the first line. If it's a known hash store it and move `block_size` lines down. If not - do not store the hash and move `1` line down.

When the whole new file is processed, you can try diff algorithm on two sequences of hashes.

This will roughly indicate how much content has changed/deleted. For added content you'll probably need to insert something additional into the second sequence.